# Request does not show all elements of website code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

Im trying to scrape the odds from a betting website for basketball games.
I have two screens open, one with python and one with the website where I inspect the elements.
However, as soon as I try to navigate through the soup by looking at the elements of the website, The code suddenly returns:

```
<div id="table-matches"></div>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I look at the elements of the website, I should still be able to navigate further. Does anyone know how it is possible that the soup does not contain all elements(/lines of code) from the website? And how should I change my code such that I can extract the odds for each game?
This is my code:

```
import bs4
import lxml
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


page = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20210102/?r=3'
req = Request(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/8.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, 'html.parser')

odds = page_soup.body.div.div.find('div', id='mother').find('div', id='wrap').div.div.div.find('div',id='col-left').find('div',id='col-content').find('div',id='table-matches')
print(odds)
```

By looking at the elements from the website, I thought I had to use `.find('table', class_='table-main')` to extract the table. However, by doing so it returns:

```
None
```

Comment: The data is being loaded with javascript, so you need to use requests-html or python selenium to scrape the rendered page.

Comment: May I recommend Selenium/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric said, the webpage is loaded with JS which means that the data are not there when you are requesting it. This is probably the data you are looking for.

Code is excluding table headers.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20210102/?r=3")
r.html.render()
page_soup = soup(r.html.html, "html.parser")

table = page_soup.table

table_rows = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in table_rows:

    td = tr.find_all("td")
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    if row:
        print(row)
```